# Upper bound for the number of maximally linearly independent subsets of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, with $|A| = m > 0$ (finite, we can assume $2^n > m > n$). I want to upper bound the number of bases of $\mathbb R^n$ contained in $A$. I do realize that a very pessimistic bound is
$$\binom{m}{n}$$
However I'm wondering whether this bound is tight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound is tight. Let $a_k=(1,k,k^2,\ldots, k^{n-1})$ for $1\le k\le m$. Then any subset of size $n$ is linearly independant because a linear dependance would lead to a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ with $n$ roots.

Comment: That's an elegant argument!

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible for your set $A$ to have the property that any subset of size $n$ from $A$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So I would say that your bound is tight.